# How to calculate total number of visible characters of QListWidgetItem in a QListView?

Tags: qt

I want to add a special character at the last visible position of a QListWidgetItem.
I'm opening the QListWidget using sizeHint.

List items contain simple texts, so I want to add blank characters till the last visible postion and then adding the special character at the last position.

How can I calculate the last visible position of QListView?

Comment: If you can get current width of column and current text, you cant calculate width of free space using [QFontMetrics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html), also you can calculate with of special character and space. After you need add `(FreeSpaceWidth - SpecialCharacterWidth) / SpaceWidth` spaces.

Comment: @Gluttton I tried it, it works. But there is a small problem. sizeHint of QListView is not giving few characters less than actually visible. I did this to get how much blank spaces I need to add. 
`(sizeHint().width() - fontMetrics().width(itemText))/fontMetrics().width(' ')` 
The problem is that sizeHint().width() seems to be giving some 5 characters less size. Am I missing to consider some spaces?

Comment: I don't sure that clearly got your point, but it seems that using `sizeHint` for detect width of item (column) is wrong approach and can be source of problems. You need really current width for this calculations. Also you forget reserve place for special character: `(currentColumn().width() - fontMetrics().width(itemText) - fontMetrics().width(specialCharacter))/fontMetrics().width(' ')`